# How to display multiple camera previews with different effects?

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHuj.jpg) on android.
Any idea on how I can do this? I couldn't find any examples that use multiple camera previews. I am aware of the library "[grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)", however from what I understood it uses 1 view (TextureView) if I'm not wrong, and then positions all the previews on it, therefor it remains a single view, which is not what I want. Each camera preview has to be separated in it's own view.

Comment: Why do they all have to be a separate views?  You should just have one cameraPreview class and overlay the color.

Comment: Hey @Minitour i had a same Problem. now i am developing a camera App and i also want to use more Camera Preview on a single activity.that is why i need solution of this Question..please tell me if you found any Best way..PLEASE...):

Comment: @Minitour Please tell me if you achived your problem solution.plz its an urgent for me.

Comment: @SagarAghara Sorry I was unable to achieve a solution. It was a part of a personal project so I dropped it.

Comment: ohhh shit.i am trying since past 15 days.